# I want to learn how to make a blog and skin it to fit into my website design theme. Any suggestions on how to get started?

Tags: dns, integration, blogs, skinning

I have never made a blog before.  I am proficient with html and css.  I know there are many blog services like "blogger" and "word press" etc where you can make a blog and even pick from skins.

Can anyone suggestions on where I can find information for a total beginner on how to use one of these services as the back end for updating my blog and have the posts show up in my own website at my own website domain?  ie have the url be www.mywebsite.com/blog as part of my website?

I really have no clue where to start.  To sum it up i need to learn how to do 2 things:

1) Skin my own blog using my knowledge of css and html and design skills - and know what service is best and why

2) How can i make this blog part of my website domain like the example url above.  Also what is this even called?  I'm not sure what the term would be to even search for it on my own.

Finally:  If anyone has any links to refer me to as a "how to guide" that will answer these specifically.. that would be great too.
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice, since you know html and css is to use [silverstripe](http://www.silverstripe.org) as your CMS.  With Silverstripe you have command over all of the html and css, rather than trying to learn the structure of someone else's markup (which is usually obscurely named).

They have a really excellent set of [tutorials](http://doc.silverstripe.com/doku.php?id=tutorials) there are only six, and once followed you will be completely proficient.  They also have modules, and a blog module is one.

Comment: hmm.  Interesting.  I'll have to get back to you after i spend some time playing with silvertype.   Is it favorable to use a full CMS over something like wordpress?  I don't much at all about CMS other than it helps you have a back end.  What are the other advantages?   Also... why silverlight?  Because its free or is it actually you're preferred one too?  thanks for your advice in advance!

Comment: I think it is.  The main advantages are you only build the html once, and every page is dynamically created with that structure, and it allows you to separate content from the process, so when you need a new page you don't need to worry about anything technical.  Silverstripe is my prefered framework, because it gives me a lot of power as a developer.

Comment: sorry, i'm quite novice with this stuff.  You say silver stripe is your prefferred framework because it gives you a lot of power as a developer, but are you talking about compared to say "wordpress" or other blog sites or compared to other CMS solutions?  Thanks again!

Comment: definetly over wordpress, and I favour it over other CMS solutions too, because of the flexibility and control over the html generated, and the power of the framework as a library to build sites with much functionality quickly. You'd have a much harder time trying to add your existing html and css to any other framework - you'll have to try a few to see what I mean..

Answer (score 1):

Follow the directions described at the link below.  It covers most of the basics of getting WordPress up and running.  From there you should be able to do whatever you want.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress

Comment: i already knew about this one.  While i haven't read through all of it yet, i did know it existed as an introduction to wordpress, yet I not sure what specifics they go into beyond using the product as a basic service or more.  I was looking for more specifics about the questions i posed above in my initial post.  thanks though!